# Totally complex submanfiolds in quaternionic Kaehlerian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Hello,

I would like to know some examples of totally complex submanifolds in quaternionic Kaehlerian manifolds, is there any references in which I could find them? So far I could not find. 
Also, the interesting example would be a holomorphic submanifold that is not totally complex in quaternionic Kaehlerian manifolds.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by totally complex? Remember, a quaternionic-Kahler manifold is not necessarily a complex manifold. [If you include hyperKahler manifolds in the class of quaternionic-Kahler manifolds, which is a matter of convention, then those would of course be complex.] Do you mean a submanifold which admits an integrable almost complex structure? If that is what you mean, what would the complex structure have to do with the ambient quaternionic-Kahler structure?

Comment: I was thinking on this: On an ambient manifold M we have 3 almost complex structures, J, K and L. And if for a submanifold N these conditions are satisfied:
1) $\nabla_{X}J=0$, for $X\in T(N)$,

2) $J(T(M))=T(M)$, $K(T(M))\bot T(M)$, $L(T(M))\bot T(M)$,

then we say that N is totally complex submanifold. 
Or maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: Well, you got two nice answers from Robert Bryant and Nina. But I wanted to add the following comment: The structures J, K, L that you mention are *not* globally well-defined on a quaternionic-Kahler manifold, unless it is hyperKahler. They are only locally defined. They give rise to (again, locally defined) Kahler forms $\omega_J$, $\omega_K$, and $\omega_L$, but the 4-form $\Phi = \omega_J^2 + \omega_K^2 + \omega_L^2$ *is* globally well-defined.

Comment: @Mirjana:  Is your definition of 'holomorphic' just a submanifold $N^{2k}\subset M^{4n}$ such that there exists a section $J:N\to Q$ so that $T_xN$ is a $J_x$-complex subspace for all $x\in N$, or do you also require that the section $J$ define an integrable almost complex structure on $N$?  (Note that a given $N$ might have more than two sections $J$ with these properties, but this is not common.)

Comment: @Robert: I don't think than J should be integrable. I wonder does the condition 1) from  my previous comment and the condition J(T(M))=T(M) necessarily imply that $K(T(M))\bot T(M)$ and $L(T(M))\bot T(M)$, for other two sections.
So, holomorphic submanifold should satisfy just the condition 1) and J(T(M)) = T(M). But, the other two conditions for K and L don't have to be satisfied.
Let's take on simple example: let $\phi:C\to C^{2}$ be an immersion. $\Omega = dz\wedge dw$ is standard complex symplectic form. $z=x+iu$; $w=y+iv$. Let $\tau$ be the standard real structure and its fixed point set

Comment: is $R^{2} = span\{x,y\}$. With $\gamma = i\Omega(.,\tau .)$ we define a Hermitian form.
Now, we calculate $\phi^{*}\gamma = \frac{\partial\phi_{1}}{\partial p}\frac{\partial\overline{\phi}_{2}}{\partial{\overline{p}}}(-2dq_{1}\wedge dq_{2}).
Here $C=span{p}$ and $p=q_{1}+iq_{2}$.
Is then $\phi$ totally complex if $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial q_{1}}=0$?

Comment: * Here $C=span\{p}$ and $p = q_{1} + i q_{2}$. Is then $\phi$ totally complex if $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial q_{1}}=0$?

Comment: @Mirjana:  **You need to fix the formatting in your comment above, as something is wrong with it that is messing up the display.  (The only way to do this, as far as I know, is to delete the comment and replace it with a new one.)**  I'm a little confused by your response.  If $\nabla_XJ=0$, then $J$ is parallel with respect to the induced metric and hence *must* be integrable.  What I was wondering was whether you just wanted to have $J(TM)=TM$.  In any case, $\nabla_XJ=0$ and $J(TM)=TM$ together do *not* imply 'totally complex; you could even have $K(TM)=TM$ and $L(TM)=TM$ in this case.

Comment: I don't have the option to delete my last two comments, so I am writing them again.

Comment: is $R^{2} = span\{x,y\}$. With $\gamma=i\Omega (.,\tau .)$ we define a Hermitian form. Now, we calculate $\phi^{*}\gamma = \frac{\partial\phi_{1}}{\partial p} \frac{\partial \overline{\phi}_{2}}{\partial\overline{p}}(-2dq_{1}\wedge dq_{2})$. Here $C=span\{p\}$ and $p = q_{1} + i q_{2}$. Is then $\phi$ totally complex if $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial q_{1}}=0$ ?

Comment: Now I am also confused about parallel condition and integrable condition for J, I have to check it. So, if an almost complex structure is parallel then it is integrable, because of Nijenhuis tensor?

Comment: Yes, I just want that condition $JT(M) = T(M)$ and not $KTM\bot TM$ and $LTM\bot TM$

Answer (score 1):

These examples are easy to come by:  Let $Q\to M$ be the canonical twistor bundle over the Q-K manifold $M^{4n}$.  Then $Q$ is a holomorphic contact manifold of complex dimension $2n{+}1$.  Now let $L\subset Q$ be any Legendrian (or sub-Legendrian) holomorphic submanifold and project it into $M$.  This will be a manifold of the desired type.

For example, if $M$ is quaternionic projective space, then $Q$ is a complex projective space, and there are many algebraic Legendrian submanifolds.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that projecting a legendrian submanifold  in $Q$  to $M$  you get again a submanifold, many singularities can occur. For example if you take one of the simplest inhomogeneous Legendrian submanifolds considered by Buczynski in "HYPERPLANE SECTIONS OF LEGENDRIAN SUBVARIETIES", (if I remember correctly) or in Landsberg Manivel "Legendrian varieties", it seems to me that the projection is not smooth.

Several examples of Totally complex submanifolds can be found in:

M. Takeuchi: Totally complex submanifolds of quaternionic symmetric spaces, Japan. J.
Math., (N.S.) 12 (1986) 161–189.

K. Tsukada: Parallel submanifolds in a Quaternion projective space, Osaka J. Math 22
(1985), 187–241.

K. Tsukada: Einstein-K ̈ahler submanifolds in a quaternion projective space, Bull. London
Math. Soc. 36 (2004), 527–536.

Bedulli-Gori-podestà "Maximal totally complex submanifolds of $\mathbb{H}\mathbb{P}^n$: homogeneity and normal holonomy" Bullettin of LMS 41 (2009) 10029--1040\

Comment: @Nina:  1. Mirjana didn't ask for compact examples or examples of maximal dimension, just for examples, of which there are plenty (local ones and of complex dimension at most $n$ when $M$ has (real) dimension $4n$), as my answer indicates.   2.  You are mistaken about projections from $Q$ to $M$ introducing image singularities (other than self-intersections) for complex Legendrian submanifolds of $Q$; any Legendrian submanifold of $Q$ is transverse to the fibers.  3.  It is true that many (sub-)Legendrian varieties in $Q$ are singular, but many are not, particularly ones with low dimension.


Comment: @Nina: Thank you for the references!

Comment: @Robert: Yes you are right, I have to say "I am not sure that ALWAYS projecting a Legendrian submanifold in Q to M you get a submanifold." In the examples that I have in mind the singularities (self-intersections) occur.


Answer (score 0):

I think this paper is also useful: arXiv:math/0308283 Complex Forms of Quaternionic Symmetric Spaces by Joseph A. Wolf. There are also several papers by Alekseevsky and Marchiafava.
Liviu